# Is it possible to change Radio button mark to checkmark that is left by `CheckMenuRadioItem()`?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a set of menu items that have to behave as exactly how radio buttons behave (once one is selected others are not marked) but the requirement is to use checkmark instead of radio button mark. Is there a possible way to modify the mark used by the `CheckMenuRadioItem()` function?

Comment: You could call the `CheckMenuItem()` function for each item in the 'group', with the 'flag' set to `MF_CHECKED` for one item and `MF_UNCHECKED` for all others.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually created another function where first I set `MF_UNCHECKED` to all of them then set the `MF_CHECK` on the one passed by argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AdrianMole is right. However [`CheckMenuItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-checkmenuitem) may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use [`SetMenuItemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfoa).

The following is an example for how to achieve this:

```
        case ID_MENU_ITEM1:
            hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
            mii.fState = MF_CHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM1, FALSE, &mii);
            mii.fState = MF_UNCHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM2, FALSE, &mii);
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM3, FALSE, &mii);
            break;
        case ID_MENU_ITEM2:
            hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
            mii.fState = MF_CHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM2, FALSE, &mii);
            mii.fState = MF_UNCHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM1, FALSE, &mii);
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM3, FALSE, &mii);
            break;
        case ID_MENU_ITEM3:
            hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
            mii.fState = MF_CHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM3, FALSE, &mii);
            mii.fState = MF_UNCHECKED;
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM1, FALSE, &mii);
            SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_MENU_ITEM2, FALSE, &mii);
            break;
```

[image]